# Get() method not recognized as a method in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

So I have some code that looks like this:

```
print('current value is %s' % self.button1.get())
```

where button1 is a Tkinter button object. But when I run the code, it returns with

> AttributeError: 'Button' object has no attribute 'get'

What's happening?

Comment: `Button` widgets do not have a `get` method.  That is only on `Text` and `Entry` widgets.  What are you trying to do here?

Answer (score 2):

The error that you're getting says it all - in Tkinter, there is no `get` method for buttons. The closest method is `cget(self, key)`, see the documentation for `Button` http://tkinter.unpythonic.net/pydoc/Tkinter.Button.html#Button-cget.

Comment: Now that I look at my code, I was trying to get the value of an Entry object.  -_- Too tired for this.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you would return the text written on the button . 
in this case just refer to the text of the button

```
print('current value is %s' % self.button1['text'])
```

or a better way is to write a method that handle the button click event

```
def OnClickButon1(self):
   print ('current value is the value you associated to the button')
   self.bt1_has_been_clicked = true
```

But you did not wrote how to set the value you want to see, edit your question to detail it to enable more accurate answer.

Comment: `self.button1.text` will give you an attribute error. That is not how you get the text of the button.